# Can we use output of look up activity directly in Data flow activity without giving any dataset in the dataflow?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I was using the look up activity to read my tables in Oracle .I want the output of Look up to be the Source of DataFlow ,Because at dataflow designer i could not connect Oracle at source side,Oracle connector is not available in Dataflow level.

So is it possible this way or is there any efficient way to do it .

Comment: 1) What is the output value? Is it a single value or a table? 
2)What do you want to do with that value in dataflow?

Comment: Its Entire Dataset table

Comment: And that table should be passed to dataflow as a source

Comment: We cannot pass lookup activity output as a source dataset to dataflow. Workaround is to copy the data to some staging storage which is supported by dataflow and use that data in  dataflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this pattern, use a Copy Activity in your pipeline prior to your Data Flow activity and stage the data in a Blob or ADLS folder, then use that dataset as the source in your data flow next in the pipeline.